# Experiences with 3rd party Polaroid film?

Tags: polaroid

[The Impossible Project](http://shop.the-impossible-project.com/shop/film/) produces [various instant films](http://www.the-impossible-project.com/) for Polaroid cameras at the original factory but using new chemicals.

To those who have tried these (or other 3rd party options, if they exist), how would you rate the quality, tone and experience with these new films, compared with original Polaroid stock?

Are there any surprises?

Comment: I'm also excited about the Impossible Project but I really wish they'd get some 4x5 sized sheets out there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TIP is the only third-party producer of polaroid integral film. Fujifilm produces peel-apart film.

Anyway, the TIP film is still very much experimental. The film is still very tempreture and light sensitive during development. You can read all about this here: http://shop.the-impossible-project.com/allabout/silvershade/ and here: http://shop.the-impossible-project.com/allabout/colorshade/

Anyway, if you're looking for original Polaroid like chracteristics, TIP film is not up to that, however they have come a long way and the film is Incredibly fun to use and can result in very nice pictures when used properly.