# What are the differences between current films available for the Polaroid SX-70 Land camera?

Tags: film, fujifilm, polaroid, instant-camera

I just purchased a `OneStep` Polaroid camera

[image]

and am so excited about starting taking pictures out there, so I've searched for film and found only these alternatives:

- [Fujifilm instant film](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000ALLYO)
- [The Impossible Project instant film](https://shop.the-impossible-project.com/shop/film/sx70)

By reading the post [Experiences with 3rd party Polaroid film?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5055/experiences-with-3rd-party-polaroid-film) I got the impression that especially for a beginner the best choice would be Fujifilm, but I wanted to ask more details about it.

So here are my questions:

- What are the main difference between the two (i.e. integral vs peel apart)?
- Are there any other options out there?
- What would be your suggestion for a newbie like me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some research on the web I [found](https://www.flickr.com/groups/polaroid_/discuss/72157594159933222/72157594217858264/) that the Fujifilm FP-100C is [not compatible](http://www.rwhirled.com/landlist/landdcam-pack.htm) with the SX-70. 
It's made for Land-100 cameras which look like [this](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Polaroid_Land_Camera_100_IMGP1932_WP.jpg).

What you need is integral film as sold by The Impossible Project.
I've experimented with their early batches of colour film and their [fade-to-black](http://www.lomography.com/magazine/reviews/2010/03/29/polaroid-tz-artistic-fade-to-black-instant-100-iso-user-review) batch using a Land 1000 camera. The results were not great in terms of sharpness and contrast, but as I understand this might be caused by the low-end camera and the early batch.
I believe TIP has fine-tuned their process of creating the film, so things should be better now.
The [sample](https://shop.the-impossible-project.com/shop/film/sx70/fi_sx70_1_imp_sx70_color_mum) [images](https://shop.the-impossible-project.com/shop/film/sx70/fi_sx70_1_imp_color_gold_mum) should give you an idea of the current quality.

Answering your question one by one:

- **Difference peel-apart and integral film** (not sure here, I've only used integral film):
  **Process**: After a shot you shield from light and wait (up to 30 minutes). With peel-apart film you wait as well, but after that you peel away the upper layer. You can do this [hours after shot is taken](http://www.japancamerahunter.com/2013/05/beginners-guide-to-polaroid-part-ii-peel-apart-film-by-phil-shen/).
  **Quality**: Looking at the different examples it seems that the [peel-apart film](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/6I96XIlxxRGZbdN20zAwoQqzGiNJHmRm6Y0WAeR_idTvakK4eKYoe_ppL-dCI-sqhLjcan-8pnBJcoAOp_ef-Gj7JzJMb49Dre6Xt4tOB6PIO4loN7bKPK-rXQ) produces higher contrast images than [the integral film](http://www.japancamerahunter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/intro_polaroid_7.jpg).
  **Size**:
  Fujifilm FP-100C: `3.25'' x 4.25''`
  Integral film for the SX-70: `3.1'' x 3.1''`
- **Other options**: Not realistically, The Impossible Project is the way to go. If you really want to you can take [Fujifilm Instax](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/instant_photo/films/instax/) and [adjust it to fit the SX-70](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zi4bhwFq9Rs), but you'll need quite some miscellaneous stuff. If you feel like experimenting, sometimes you can find expired integral film for sale for a reduced price. The results of using such film [are unpredictable](https://www.flickr.com/groups/sx-70/pool/tags/expired/).
- **Suggestion for a newbie**: Get the Impossible Project film. It's sort of "plug and play" and will enable you to learn to use instant film without much hassle. Downside: it's pretty expensive. If you find yourself in the neighborhood of [Enschede, The Netherlands](https://goo.gl/maps/iK4Dg) see if the TIP has a sale where you can drop by. They sometimes have some left-over stock which they sell with a discount (I've only encountered this once, but who knows).

Comment: great answer, what I was looking for!thanks. Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by not compatible? it won't fit or something else?

Comment: Yes, it has different dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll wait a bit so that your answer can get more attention and then accept and give you the bounty ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Definitely wait longer, no hurry. This will give other members the chance to correct me, add their own answers or ask for clarification.

Comment: won't the images in an SX 70 using instax film be reversed?